# Phone menu code java

Tags: java, menu

I am doing a coding assignment that requires us to create a phone menu of some sort and I was wonder how this can be done. For example, a caller calls the system and the system prompts the user to press 1 to do action a, 2 to do action b. if the called presses 2, the system prompts the user if they would like to skip back to the last phase to pick a new action. What is the best way to implement something like this?

Comment: Please first show what you've tried, or failing that, at least your thoughts/guesses on what you should do.

Comment: If a console program, you will want to use a loop such as a while loop to "skip back".  But again, give us your thoughts on this too so we can help you better.

Answer (score 0):

- Structure the menu hierarchically
- Use `System.out` to show the menu
- Use `System.in` to get the input from the user

Simple ain't it?

Answer (score 0):

From the sound of it, you will be using the AWT or Swing library. These libraries have a concept of event and listener, which basically means you can set something to listen to each button, and react when it is pressed/moused over/etc. Google will be your friend here (and through most of your coding career), but I recommend this link to begin: http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/
Also, if you have a textbook assigned, look for appropriate articles in that, naturally.

The SO crowd will not design this for you. However, when you have trouble with actual code, we can possibly help with that.

Also, if you're looking to use your keyboard (and not a graphical representations of a dialpad), the AWT/Swing library has support for key press event that you can link up too.

Hope this helps!